# How to use SignInWithRedirect with GoogleAuthProvider?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, vuejs2

I am creating a Vue App (Vue version 2). I am using Firebase (Web version 9) as a database and for the authentication. I am using Google as Sign in method. On desktop I want to use the signInWithPopup method, which works perfectly fine. However they recommend using signInWithRedirect on mobile. I do not understand how this second method have to be used. Here is what I have done so far :

```
googleSignIn: async function () {
    const auth = getAuth();
    const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
    try {
        let result;
        if (this.isMobile) {
            await signInWithRedirect(auth, provider);
            result = await getRedirectResult(auth);
            if (result) {
                console.log(result);
            } else {
                console.log("no result");
            }
        } else {
            result = await signInWithPopup(auth, provider);
        }
        const googleUser = result.user;
        const query = await db
           .collection("users")
           .where("email", "==", googleUser.email)
           .get();
        if (!query.empty) {
           this.$store.dispatch("setUser", googleUser.reloadUserInfo);
            this.$router.push({ path: "/dashboard" });
        } else {
            alert("impossible de se connecter");
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

Here are my imports :

```
import { getAuth, signInWithPopup, signInWithRedirect, getRedirectResult, GoogleAuthProvider, } from "firebase/auth";
```

Comment: What is not working as intended here? The code seems fine as in the docs.

Comment: @Dharmaraj when i clicked on the google account, it takes my back to the login page and not to the home page, as if no data were returned. I've edited my question so you can see what's after

Comment: Does it log the `result` or `"no result"` in console? Also do you have any `onAuthStatechanged`observer anywhere?

Comment: Nothing is printed in the console. No I do not have a "onAuthStatechanged" that might be the thing

Comment: Can you try adding a log statement right before try block starts? so we know at least the function is being invoked

Comment: The function is being invoked as i am redirect to a google page where i have to choose the account i want to login with. But I am not redirect to my "dashboard" page when the google page closes

Comment: Have you solved it?

Comment: Yes i did, i had to call the "getRedirectResult" at my component "mounted"

Answer (score 0):

Use cicle life mounted:

```
mounted(){
authFire.getRedirectResult(authFire.auth)
.then((result)=>{
if(result!=null){
}
  })
},
```